# How can I use chrome dev tools to pinpoint the cause of elements on my page shifting?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Something at the top of my page is causing a major layout shift in content.
The content renders, then jumps upward like 300px, then jumps back down to it's normal position.

I have tried stepping through the code, but this only seems useful if you know where you want the code to stop.

How can I use the dev tools to effectively locate the javascript and/or element that is causing this issue?

[Here is the site](https://revolutionparts.com)

Comment: Rather than just linking the troublesome site, could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the performance tool in Chrome you can record your session.
You can hover over the screenshots until you see the page changing. In this case just as that jump happens you see an "onLoad" event

This could suggest that there is some javascript loading on page load event that alters your styles ?

[image]

Clicking on the anonymous function or any of those event will allow you to see in the summary where in the source code this is happening.

[image]

Then you can set a break point in the code where this is happening. (click the line number to the left of the line)

Keep trying this until you find what might be your problem

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am playing around with these suggestions.